# Animate Portions of Web Page with JQuery

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draw

I would like to build some portions of my page that look like they are being drawn on the page when the page loads.

For example: When the page loads I want to draw a 3px high line from left to right the width of the current page. About half way through that line I want to draw a line from top to bottom the height of the current page. When they are done I want to fade in some text as the logo or images. Then pop up (fade in) the navigation bar.

This might sound easier in Flash, but I don't want to use flash. I don't understand it and don't really have the patience to learn it. I do however grasp the concept of code, jquery, php, mysql and really enjoying using it. Just don't understand if I can do what I want in Jquery how I want to do it.

I'm asking if I can essentially create a UI with JQuery upon page load and have it build these elements. 
Thanks,

Comment: You could also look into html5 canvas rendering and such.

Comment: What you described doesn't sound like it would require canvas. jQuery should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is simple enough and should be absolutely possible with jQuery. Check out jQuery's [animate() function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Between that and some CSS, you should be set. Try using divs and setting border styles to appear as the lines. Alternatively, you can use HRs.

Comment: This was really helpful but can you help me further with being able to animate different "id" div's? I can grow a line like I want in two directions but I am going to have multiple divs on the page when I am done and in different locations for the animation.